# JAVA So I need help Iterating through a JSONArray

Tags: java, json, swing, jtable

Im using a `JTable` which require an `Object[][]` for the data for the rows and a `String[]` full of Column names.

Im having a hard time sliding the data into the first set of elements into the `Object[][]` by building another `Object[]` and filling it up with the `itemDetails`.

The way I'm saving the Items is I made two new Classes `Item` and `SoldItem`.

**Item.Java**

```
package com.johnwillikers.inventory;

import com.johnwillikers.Core;
import com.johnwillikers.io.Out;

public class Item {

    public String id;
    public String name;
    public String desc;
    public String paidDate;
    public int paidPrice;

    public Item(String id, String name, String desc, String paidDate ,int paidPrice){
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.desc = desc;
        this.paidDate = paidDate;
        this.paidPrice = paidPrice;
    }

    public String getId(){
        return this.id;
    }

    public String getName(){
        return this.name;
    }

    public String getDesc(){
        return this.desc;
    }

    public String getPaidDate(){
        return this.paidDate;
    }

    public int getPaid(){
        return this.paidPrice;
    }

    public void saveItem(){
        Out.saveItem(id, name, desc, paidDate, Core.saveItemCodeString, paidPrice, Core.saveItemCode);
    }

    public void destroy() throws Throwable{
        this.finalize();
    }
}
```

**SoldItem.java**

```
package com.johnwillikers.inventory;

import com.johnwillikers.io.Out;

public class SoldItem {

    public String id;
    public String name;
    public String desc;
    public String paidDate;
    public String soldDate;
    public int paidPrice;
    public int soldPrice;

    public SoldItem(String id, String name, String desc, String paidDate, String soldDate, int paidPrice, int soldPrice){
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.desc = desc;
        this.paidDate = paidDate;
        this.soldDate = soldDate;
        this.paidPrice = paidPrice;
        this.soldPrice = soldPrice;
    }

    public String getId(){
        return this.id;
    }

    public String getName(){
        return this.name;
    }

    public String getDesc(){
        return this.desc;
    }

    public String getPaidDate(){
        return this.paidDate;
    }

    public String getSoldDate(){
        return this.soldDate;
    }

    public int getPaid(){
        return this.paidPrice;
    }

    public int getSold(){
        return this.soldPrice;
    }

    public int getProfit(){
        return this.soldPrice - this.paidPrice; 
    }

    public void saveItem(){
        Out.saveItem(id, name, desc, paidDate, soldDate ,paidPrice, soldPrice);
    }

    public void destroy(){
        this.destroy();
    }

}
```

So these classes both have a .save function that calls one function from my io.Out class

**Out.java**

```
package com.johnwillikers.io;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import com.johnwillikers.Core;

public class Out {

    /*
     * Written to keep me from adding so much every-time I needed to print. - John <3 
     */
    public static void print(File file, String string)throws IOException{
        PrintWriter pr = new PrintWriter(file);
        pr.println(string);
        pr.close();
    }

    /*
     * This function is in charge of saving both Items and SoldItems. It checks to see if soldPrice == Core.saveItemCode
     * if it is it will save the information as an Item and anything else as a SoldItem. I.e use Core.saveItemCode if you
     * intend to save an Item and not a SoldItem. - John <3
     */
    public static boolean saveItem(String id, String name, String desc, String paidDate, String soldDate, int paidPrice, int soldPrice){
        //Saving Item
        if(soldPrice == 20000000 || soldDate == "00/00/0000"){
            File save = new File(Core.itemsDir.toString() + "/" + id + ".json");
            if(save.exists())
                save.delete();
            try{
                JSONObject item = new JSONObject().put("id", id).put("name", name).put("desc", desc).put("paidDate", paidDate).put("paidPrice", paidPrice);
                print(save, item.toString());
                return true;
            }catch(IOException e){
                return false;
            }
        //Saving SoldItem
        }else{
            File save = new File(Core.soldItemsDir.toString() + "/" + id + ".json");
            if(save.exists())
                save.delete();
            try{
                JSONObject item = new JSONObject().put("id", id).put("name", name).put("desc", desc).put("paidDate", paidDate).put("soldDate", soldDate).put("paidPrice", paidPrice).put("soldPrice", "soldPrice");
                print(save, item.toString());
                return true;
            }catch(IOException e){
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    /*
     * Written to save the settings file. Returns true on success false on failure
     */
    public static boolean saveSettings(){
        JSONObject settings = new JSONObject();
        try{
            print(Core.settingsFile, settings.toString());
            return true;
        }catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }catch(JSONException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
    }

    public static boolean appendItemsFile(String id){
        if(!Core.itemsFile.exists()){
            JSONArray items = new JSONArray().put(id);
            JSONObject itemsFile = new JSONObject().put("Items", items);
            try {
                print(Core.itemsFile, itemsFile.toString());
                return true;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
                return false;
            }
        }else{
            try {
                JSONObject itemsFile = In.readItem(Core.itemsFile);
                JSONArray items = itemsFile.getJSONArray("Items");
                items.put(id);
                itemsFile.put("Items", items);
                print(Core.itemsFile, itemsFile.toString());
                return true;
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
                return false;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    public static boolean appendSoldItemsFile(String id){
        if(!Core.soldItemsFile.exists()){
            JSONArray items = new JSONArray().put(id);
            JSONObject itemsFile = new JSONObject().put("Items", items);
            try {
                print(Core.itemsFile, itemsFile.toString());
                return true;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
                return false;
            }
        }else{
            try {
                JSONObject itemsFile = In.readItem(Core.itemsFile);
                JSONArray items = itemsFile.getJSONArray("Items");
                items.put(id);
                itemsFile.put("Items", items);
                Core.soldItemsFile.delete();
                print(Core.soldItemsFile, itemsFile.toString());
                return true;
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
                return false;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then I load them in with which just return the whole .json file as a JSONObject. Right now im trying to build a basic structure. there are 2 files `Items_registry.json` and `Sold_Items_Registry.json`. They have one key and it is `Items` which holds a JSONArray full of ID numbers. The ID number is then take and helped to find a file like this `./Items/id.json`. It loads the details into the one Object[] and then trys to load that into `Object[][]` for the table. The problem is that I can't find a way to keep up with the element. Below is my `ItemTable` class that builds the `Table`

**ItemTable.Java**

```
package com.johnwillikers.gui;

import java.awt.Dimension;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class ItemTable extends JPanel{

    public static Object[][] itemsData;

    public ItemTable(){
        super(new GridLayout(1,0));

        String[] columnNames = {"Id", "Name", "Paid", "Date", "Description"};

        try {
            //Load the Items_Registry.jon then get the Items array out
            JSONObject itemsFile = In.readItem(Core.itemsFile);
            JSONArray items = itemsFile.getJSONArray("Items");

            //Iterate through every element and search for it's ID in the Items folder then load the information into an Object[]
            items.forEach(id -> {
                String item = (String) id;
                In.getItems(item);
            });
            final JTable table = new JTable(itemsData, columnNames);
            table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(500, 70));
            table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
            JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
            add(scrollPane);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

If you need anymore code, I tend to update the [dev branch](https://github.com/BrianMiltonJr/Inventory_Management/tree/dev) as much as possible so check it out if you need more information. If there is a more easier way of doing this besides json I would love to hear!

EDIT: forgot to add `In.Java` for `getItems` method.

**In.java**

```
package com.johnwillikers.io;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import com.johnwillikers.Core;
import com.johnwillikers.gui.ItemTable;

public class In {

    public static JSONObject readItem(File file) throws JSONException, IOException{
        FileReader fr = new FileReader(file);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
        JSONObject item = new JSONObject(br.readLine());
        br.close();
        return item;
    }

    public static void getItems(String item){
        try {
            JSONObject itemDetailsRaw = In.readItem(new File(Core.itemsDir + item + ".json"));
            Object [] itemDetails = {itemDetailsRaw.get("id"), itemDetailsRaw.get("name"), itemDetailsRaw.get("paidDate"), itemDetailsRaw.get("desc")};
            int index = ItemTable.itemsData.length;
            ItemTable.itemsData[index] = itemDetails;
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    public static void setSettings(){
        if(!Core.settingsFile.exists())
            try {
                JSONObject settings = new JSONObject().put("derp", "herp");
                Out.print(Core.settingsFile, settings.toString());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        try {
            JSONObject settings = readItem(Core.settingsFile);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `Im using a JTable which require an Object[][] for the data for the rows and a String[] full of Column names` - no you don't need a 2Dimensional array. You can create a DefaultTableModel with just the columnNames and 0 rows of data. Then you can use the addRow(...) method to add individual rows of data. This is much easier than trying to guess what the size of the Array should be.

Comment: @camickr I made a DefaultTableModel and it works perfectly man! Thanks for the help!